# How do I get write access to my external hard drive?

Tags: 14.04, mount, permissions, hard-drive, external-hdd

I have recently formatted an external hard drive for use with Ubuntu 14.04 using GParted. I formatted the drive to Ext4, and everything seemed to work until I tried to copy files to the drive, at which point I was stopped with an error saying that the device is read-only. I have read many other questions here and elsewhere regarding changing permissions and remounting, but I have been unsuccessful with all of them.

Here's a picture of my permissions window for the drive:

[image]

And since I've seen requests for it in other places, here's an output of `sudo fdisk -l`: http://pastebin.com/GSpNGSJU (`/dev/sdh/`, the 2 TB drive, is the one I want to write to. `/dev/sda/` is my internal hard drive.)

I'm really at a loss. I've tried remounting the drive with various suggested options, I've tried recursively updating permissions with `sudo chmod`, I've tried reformatting to make sure I'm not on NTFS - In short, I've tried a lot of things, but I'm so frustrated now that I'm having a hard time knowing if anything that I've done has actually been done correctly. What's more, my particular question doesn't seem to be answered elsewhere (unless I haven't looked hard enough), so there's that.

Hopefully I'm missing something simple, but how do I make it so that I can actually write to my hard drive?

Comment: So, `sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sdXB` doesn't work? (X=drive,B=partition)

Comment: I had tried that previously, but I just tried it again to be sure, and no, it doesn't seem to work. I first tried `sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sdh` (without the 1), and that threw an error, so I went with partition 1. That went through okay, but the drive is still read-only.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure it's the right drive? Also try a different port.

Comment: I have redundantly verified that there are only two drives connected: my (one) internal hard drive and my (one uncooperative) external drive. After running `sudo fdisk -l` again, I can confirm that `/dev/sda` is my internal drive due to its many recognizable partitions and `/dev/sdh` is my external drive by elimination. I tried `sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sdh1`, and that executed without error, but I still can't write to my drive. Would something as simple as a machine restart affect this? Edit: Oh, and what do you mean by different port? There is only one listed partition.

Comment: Have you an entry in your `/etc/fstab` for this device?

Comment: I think so. Here's the output: http://pastebin.com/yp8SmAGQ I think I put the last comment and line in as a part of another failed solution, though, so maybe it's wrong. I see `exfat` there. Does that make a difference since the filesystem on the drive now is `ext4`?

Comment: How many partitions are on `sdh`?

Comment: There is exactly one partition on `/dev/sdh`. This is verified here: http://pastebin.com/GSpNGSJU , and by GParted here: http://imgur.com/Okd8qLD

Comment: In the intervening time, I got the drive to be writable simply by deleting the line in question and rebooting. (I had added it myself previously, so I didn't see the harm.) `/etc/fstab` now reads: http://pastebin.com/vg6nVkuU , which is how it was when I started, I think. (Note that I've unmounted the drive to work on other things, if that matters.) As requested, here's `/etc/mtab`, but I think my problem is solved regardless: http://pastebin.com/1NnwXANU Thanks to everyone for the help.